Remove everything before 2nd occurrence of character SQL
Evening experts. Can anybody help with this MySQL query?
I need to remove everything before the last occurrence of the character |
I have a database table with a fileinfo column but the file information also includes unwanted text. I gathered the data from a scrape of a website of mine and although using regex it still captures the unwanted text before the actual fileinfo.
I have done my homework but struggled to compile a working query.
So far I have the following query which throws an immediate error:

Unrecognised statement type. (near "IF" at position 0)

IF (INSTR(fileinfo,'|') > 1, LEFT (fileinfo, INSTR(fileinfo,'|')-1),fileinfo);

Here is an example of the data in a random fileinfo column:
| 25 October 2024 | 500.68 MB

I want to remove from my database all data before the last occurrence of the character |
so all that remains would be 500.68 MB.
Any help or a working query would be great. I'm really new to SQL. I've got the basics down Select, Update, Delete etc., but anything especially complex I'm struggling to find solutions for, even though I Google it, find the query but then get said error.
I am using Cpanel SQL.

IF is a function, so you need something like select if(3>2,'foo','bar') as stackoverflow;

If fileinfo is a column, you need SELECT IF(...) FROM tablename;

SELECT substring_index('| 25 October 2024 | 500.68 MB','|',-1) as last;

output:



last




500.68 MB



More info: SUBSTRING_INDEX
EDIT: "remove all instances from every product "
UPDATE test
SET t = substring_index(t,'|',-1)
-- WHERE ....... you should add an expression here when you do not want to update ALL records

see: DBFIDDLE

Thats Great, However i need a query that will parse the whole database , Thank you

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '('|',-1) as last LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

@Robertwall: I do not see a problem with MariaDB 10.6 (https://dbfiddle.uk/oH7y7ydt)

@Robertwall:  You may need a query, but then you should learn SQL, ( see: https://dbfiddle.uk/O3czL1mW for an example )

But how do i use that query to remove all instances from every product in the database..
i know i can manually 1 by 1 do this, but i can manually 1 by 1 do it anyway using Cpanel on my website... But that would take forever.. i have 63,000++ products to alter. I thought everybody on stackoverflow where genius lol

I edited my answer, and added from free SQL course material
